# Blue Prism - Not able to spy elements - Browser Firefox

Tags: automation, robotics, blueprism, rpa

I have an issue with spy Browser mode in Firefox.
I have designed a new RPA process on Dev machine where I have spy in Browser mode (in firefox) web page.
On my Dev machine the Browser mode is working good and the process runs very good.
The issue is on production machine where the modeler don't see the elements which have been spied on dev machine.

Actions so far done.
We have set all settings regarding Firefox to the same like on dev machine using the BP guide,
We have installed the same Firefox extension on prod like on dev machine.
We have set the same internet options.

Non of the actions have helped us to be able to spy elements in Firefox on prod machine.

My questions to the experts community:)
What else could have impact on the BP - Browser mode which is stopping BP to see elements?
What virtual machine settings need to be set/or what to check?

We have BP Version 6:
Application Manager 6.4.2.10610
.Net Framework 4.7
Firefox version 72.0.2
Blue Prism Browser Extension version 6.4.2.10610vycoxormiz (updated 30. Jan. 2020)

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution.

During investigation I came on this link

[https://superuser.com/questions/719875/google-chrome-always-says-google-chrome-was-not-shut-down-properly][1]

In the location "%UserProfile%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Preferences

I have changed the "exit_type": "normal" to "exit_type": "standard" and immediate the

Browser mode on production machine was working and we could run the process.

It seems that the chrome when it wasn't shut down properly has impact on Blue Prism.

Adding update.
I have noticed that each time Chrome opens it changes in the Preferences file the status to Normal.
I have fixed the issue in that way, that I have added additional logic to my solution:
1. I have copied the Preferences file to a different location and changed in the file the status to Standard.
2. I have added additional logic to my process where bot copy the file from the new location and replace the file in the Chrome location each time he runs.

Hope this will help others with similar issue.

Regards!